Can we still be a realist even though we recognize that there is no absolute empirical basis?
Can we still be a realist even though we recognize that there is no absolute empirical basis?
Carnap developed a program for an irrefutable and invariable empirical basis. The idea was that it is possible to build an invariable set of irrefutable observation utterances (utterances that linguistically describe perceptive experiences), on which science can rely.
It was found that the empirical basis is not absolute but relative to the state of knowledge (The logic of scientific discovery, Popper), and therefore this idea should be dismissed.
Can we still be a realist even though we recognize that there is no absolute empirical basis?

Yes, there's no "absolute basis" for just about anything.

One can be a realist even with no empirical basis at all, they can hold that the truth of reality comes instead from divine revelation or mystic intuition or spiritual enlightenment. And even scientific realism may well be pragmatic, with no 'absolutes', Peirce was an avowed scientific realist and a fallibilist at the same time, so was Quine, at least in declarations. Even the more traditional realists allow that parts of "empirical basis" can be revised and/or reinterpreted, albeit not all of them at once. Realism is about plausibility of ontology, not epistemological certainty.

@Conifold "Peirce was an avowed scientific realist and a fallibilist at the same time, so was Quine, at least in declarations", but Quine said that the question "what exists" doesn't make sense, because it can only receive response inside of a given language. On the other hand, we can read that Quine was a realist, and even the scientific realist per excellence......

That is not quite how he said it, he rather deflated the meaning of "truth" and "existence", and declared himself a realist right after nonetheless, even a physicalist. He said he believed in electrons, etc., and even argued for  existence of sets and numbers, physicalism notwithstanding, because they are indispensable to science and physics in particular.
